# PermissionError: [WinError 32] when importing the requests module

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-requests

When I run the command `import requests`, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 170, in exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpz9h1wrjd'
```

If I delete the file at the bottom of the error, it generates a new random file and the new file comes up in the error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, baruch Hashem! I:

1. Uninstalled python
2. Deleted the `Lib` folder in `C:/User/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39` and `C:/User/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python31`0
3. Re-installed python.

It works!

Comment: Mmm, this obviously is the hard way that works... but I guess there is a better option...

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Visual Studio Code?

If the answer is yes, than it might be the problem. Try reinstalling it and the PYTHON extension.

More info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/65069).

Answer (score 0):

No need to delete and reinstall Python completely when you are using virtual environments.

This is very useful to keep python environment separated from one project to another.

Just (re)create a new Python venv. Tested successfully. You can use Anaconda Navigator on Windows to do that easily.

On Linux, just run the following commands of a terminal: `conda create --name py35 python=3.5` (here we specify the name of the venv to be py35 and we select Python 3.5 as default Python in the venv. Then run `source activate py34` to activate the venv and `source deactivate` to go back to default one. More commands and info [here | cheatsheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf).

More info here: [Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)